# make the markers in the plot more visible

Tags: python, matplotlib, gradient-descent

I want to draw the progress of the gradient descent.

I start with the function "f" and the partial derivation of the function and start the gradient descent with the parameters you see in the code.

When I plot the 3D graph of the function and the points of the gradient descent which i store during the iterations, the markers of the progress aren't good visible.

```
def f(X,Y):
    return (X**2) + (2*(Y**2)) + (2*X*Y) - (6*X) - (16*Y) + (41)
     

def derivation_x(X, Y):
    return (2*X) + (2*Y) - (6)


def derivation_y(X,Y):
    return (2*X) + (4*Y) - (16)


def gradient_step(x, y,lr=0.0000001 ):
    new_x = derivation_x(x, y) * lr
    new_y = derivation_y(x, y) * lr
    return new_x, new_y


def lost_z(x,y):
    return f(x,y)


def gradientenDescent(startx, starty):
    
    new_x, new_y = gradient_step(startx, starty, lr=0.005 )

    diffx = startx - new_x
    diffy= starty - new_y
    return diffx, diffy

# I start the folling in a jupyter cell
_____________________________
start_x, start_y =  -20 ,-20  
points = []
for iteratrion in range(250):
    
        
    x_step, y_step = gradientenDescent(start_x, start_y)
    newlost = lost_z(x_step, y_step  )
    points.append([start_x, start_y, newlost])
    if iteratrion % 10 == 0:
        print("iteratrion:" + str(iteratrion))
        print("x:" + str(start_x) +  "  y:" + str(start_y))
        print("Z:" + str(newlost))
        print("___________________")
    start_x, start_y =  x_step, y_step

___________________________________


size = 12
X, Y = np.linspace(-25,25,25), np.linspace(-25,25,25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)
fig = plt.figure(figsize= (size,size))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface( X ,Y,  f(X,Y), cmap="jet", alpha = 0.6)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')



for i in range(len(points)): 
    ax.scatter(points[i,0],points[i,1],points[i,2],color='r', marker='x', alpha = 1) 
    


ax.elev = 270
ax.azim = 270  # xz view

ax.elev = 180
ax.azim = 180    # yz view

ax.elev = 15
ax.azim = 15 # xy view
plt.show()
_________________________
```

So now i want the markers be more visible as it is now.

[here is the Image matplotlib draw so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbcDz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Scatters are hidden by the 3dSurface. To avoid this you can use the following:

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d', computed_zorder=False)
...
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, f(X, Y), cmap="jet", alpha=0.6,zorder=1)
...
for i in range(len(points)):
    ax.scatter(points[i,0],points[i,1],points[i,2],color='r', marker='x', alpha = 1, zorder=2, s=21)
```

use `s=21` to change the size of xmarks. maybe it would also look nice if a cmap would be used for the scatters instead of an static color